# Открыть ссылку определённый браузером

Tags: html

Как открыть ссылку в определённом браузере? То есть в системе установлено 2 браузера хром и IE есть сайт который корректно работает только в хроме и есть сайт которые корректно работают только в IE. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: на чем система? apache+linux? php?

Comment: Система Windows, сайт написан при помощи html и JS

Comment: То есть, вы хотите вести на страницу, где работает в текущем браузере (это в приципе возможно), или хотите открывать другой браузер (это не возможно с JS)?

Comment: Может появились способы? Скайп, Телеграмм, Зум и т.д. - открываются же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом, стандартных способов открыть страницу в другом браузере нет.
Т.к. это требует запуска на пользовательском компьютере новой программы (браузера), что в свою очередь не является безопасным.

Если говорить о нестандартных способах, то можно в IE через ActiveX это реализовать, но это неуниверсально и тот еще костыль.

Так что рекомендую пересмотреть вариант реализации и подумать о другом способе решения проблемы. Например отдавать контент в зависимости от заголовка User-Agent, если этот функционал нужен для собственных сайтов, а не каких-то внешних ресурсов.

Comment: Ясно, тогда буду искать решение как заставить IE открыть мой сайт. В хроме он нормально отображается а в IE часть открывает часть нет(

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то Вы хотите следующий функционал. Пользователь открывает ссылку в браузере. Если браузер подходит тогда сайт в нем отображается если не подходит - не отображается.
Для реализации такого функционала Вам нужно задействовать какой то язык программирования. Пример на PHP с использованием библиотеки 
 [php-browser-detector](https://github.com/sinergi/php-browser-detector):

```
use Sinergi\BrowserDetector\Browser;

$browser = new Browser();
if ($browser->getName() === $browser::IE && $browser->getVersion() > 11) {
    echo 'контент который будет отображаться в експлорере выше 11 версии';
}
```